CONSULDEMOCRACY: Sass fails (sassc-embeded-import stylesheet not found)
User Story
I am trying to deploy a local instance of consuledemocracy and if fails with Sass::CompileError
Description
My system is an Ubuntu 22.04 and i use the following versions:
Rails v6.1.7.7
NodeJS v18.18.2
PSQL v14.11
Ruby v3.2.3
I have followed the steps for the local installation and although the server can be deployed (bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0), when visiting localhost I get the following error:
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5267ms (ActiveRecord: 165.5ms | Allocations: 3295956)

ActionView::Template::Error (Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import "sassc-embedded-import:19";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  sassc-embedded-import:18 1:9                                                        @import
  /home/singular/consul/consuldemocracy/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss 10:9  root stylesheet):

sassc-embedded (1.70.1) lib/sassc/embedded.rb:66:in `rescue in render'
sassc-embedded (1.70.1) lib/sassc/embedded.rb:13:in `render'
sassc-rails (2.1.2) lib/sassc/rails/template.rb:40:in `block in call'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:145:in `block in module_include'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:130:in `synchronize'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:130:in `module_include'
sassc-rails (2.1.2) lib/sassc/rails/template.rb:39:in `call'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
...
...

when I run bin/rails assets:precompile I get:
singular@euprojects: ~/consul/consuldemocracy$ bin/rails assets:precompile
rails aborted!
SassC::SyntaxError: Error: Can't find stylesheet to import. (SassC::SyntaxError)
  ╷
1 │ @import "sassc-embedded-import:19";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  sassc-embedded-import:18 1:9                                                        @import
  /home/singular/consul/consuldemocracy/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss 10:9  root stylesheet

Caused by:
Sass::CompileError: Can't find stylesheet to import. (Sass::CompileError)

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)


Seems to me that a stylesheet is missing but I can't find any information online.

Can you confirm the version you are Using? The addition of the sassc-embedded-import gem appears to have been committed to master last week, where as the mot recent version (2.1.1) was released 2024-03-21. Maybe try using git clone https://github.com/consuldemocracy/consuldemocracy.git --branch 2.1.1 --single-branch and see if that works?
